# Asp.net - remember me - user always authenticate issue

Tags: asp.net, remember-me

I try to implement a remember me fonctionnality for my asp.net website.

Scenario:
The user log in without checked "remember me" checkbox.
He logout or close the tab/browser.

The issue:
When the user come back to the login page, he is see as connected as if he checked "remember me".

This is the code of Login.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myCookies = Request.Cookies;
    HttpCookie authCookie = myCookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);

    if (authCookie != null) // Always true!
    { 
        HttpContext page = HttpContext.Current;

        System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity = page.User.Identity;

        if (identity.IsAuthenticated) // Always true!
        {
            //do some data loading

            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx?p=Profil");


        }
    }
    else if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
    }
}

protected void LoginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (userCredentialValid())
    {
        HttpCookie formAuthCook;
        Response.Cookies.Clear();

        if (LoginUser.RememberMeSet)
        {
            DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, LoginUser.UserName, DateTime.Now, expiryDate, true, String.Empty);
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            formAuthCook = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            formAuthCook.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
            formAuthCook.HttpOnly = true;
            formAuthCook.Secure = true;

            Response.Cookies.Add(formAuthCook);
        }
        else
        {
            formAuthCook = mesCookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            if (formAuthCook != null)
            {
                formAuthCook.Expires = DateTime.Now;
                Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            }
        }

        e.Authenticated = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }

}
```

Thanks beforehand!

EDIT: Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This could be a browser issue. Chrome has functionality automatically enabled as do other browsers. They persist cookies even when the developer of a site wishes it not to do so. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513

Comment: Interesting! But the problem is the same with Firefox...

Comment: Firefox offers the same functionality I believe as do many browsers. You can test it by disabling that "feature" to see if its related to that or not.

Comment: I can't find the "Disable Better session restore" in chrome://flags/...

Comment: I tried to add a key to authentication cookie if remember me is set like: formAuthCook["IsPersistent"] = "1";
But in page load the key disappears...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround!

I create a cookie to specify when the session is persistent:

```
protected void LoginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (userCredentialValid())
    {
        HttpCookie formAuthCook;
        Response.Cookies.Clear();

        if (LoginUser.RememberMeSet)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Clear();
            //set the new expiry date – to thirty days from now
            DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            //create a new forms auth ticket
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, LoginUser.UserName, DateTime.Now, expiryDate, true, String.Empty);
            //encrypt the ticket
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            //create a new authentication cookie – and set its expiration date
            formAuthCook = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            formAuthCook.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
            formAuthCook.HttpOnly = true;
            formAuthCook.Secure = true;

            //######################### EDIT #################################
            HttpCookie sCookPersistent = new HttpCookie("pSession"); //In my code I use a constante for cookie name
            sCookPersistent.Value = "1";
            sCookPersistent.HttpOnly = true;
            sCookPersistent.Secure = true;
            sCookPersistent.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
            ////######################### EDIT END ##########################

            //add the cookie to the response.
            Response.Cookies.Add(formAuthCook);
            Response.Cookies.Add(sCookPersistent);//##### EDIT
        }
        else
        {
            formAuthCook = mesCookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            if (formAuthCook != null)
            {
                formAuthCook.Expires = DateTime.Now;
                Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            }

            //######################### EDIT #################################
            if (Request.Cookies["pSession"] != null)
            {
                Request.Cookies["pSession"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
                Response.Cookies.Remove("pSession");
            }
            ////######################### EDIT END ###########################
        }

        e.Authenticated = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}
```

And in the page load:

```
HttpCookieCollection myCookies = Request.Cookies;            
HttpCookie authCookie = myCookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
bool authCookieValid = false;

if (authCookie != null)
{
    //Cookie created if the user checked the remember me checkbox
    //if null the session is not persistent
    if (Request.Cookies["pSession"] == null)
    {
        authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now;
        Response.Cookies.Set(authCookie);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCookie.Value))
    {
        authCookieValid = true;
    }
}
```

It is not bulletproof but it does the job for now.

If you guys have suggestions, let me know. :)